# C++ getting : in the regex

Tags: c++, regex, string

I use the following statement to get the user string input in the console:

`std::getline(std::cin, variable);`

And it captures it. I then want to split the whole string by space, so I use the following regex rule"

```
std::string EachWord = "([a-zA-Z:/\\]+)"; // I also have used \: than :
regex reg_rule(this->cmdrepo.EachWord);
// and the rest of regex capturing
```

The problem is that, it captures everything, but does not capture `:`, and treats it as a space, so this string `--setCurrent E://folder/` is split into:

```
1- setCurrent
2- E // instead, it should be E://folder
```

What should I do?

Comment: This might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/split-a-string-in-c regex is not the most efficient method to split a string.

Comment: yes I checked it. Thanks much...